# Issue Updating date with Oracle and PHP

Tags: php, oracle

Im doing a Crud with PHP and Oracle, adding the info and deleting the info works fine. But Updating is not saving on the oracle database. Im sure that is something related to the DATE format, because I had the same project with other database and doesnt have any problem. Any guess, whats it happening?

```
     <?php
    require_once 'conexion.php';
  $idautor = $_POST['ID_AUTOR'];
  $nameautor = $_POST['NOMBRE_AUTOR'];
 $bdate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($_POST['FECHA_NACIMIENTO'])); 

$query = "UPDATE  AUTOR  SET NOMBRE_AUTOR ='".$nameautor."', FECHA_NACIMIENTO ='".$bdate."' WHERE ID_AUTOR = '".$idautor."' ";
 // $query = "UPDATE  AUTOR  SET NOMBRE_AUTOR ='".$nameautor."' WHERE ID_AUTOR = '".$idautor."' ";
    $statement = oci_parse($conexion,$query);
    $r = oci_execute($statement,OCI_DEFAULT);
     $res = oci_commit($conexion);


  

   if ($res) {
    // Mensaje si los datos cambian 
    echo "<script>alert('Los libros se actualizaron con exito'); window.location.href='sistema.php'</script>";
    header('Location: sistema.php'); 
  } else {
    // Mensaje si los datos no cambian 
    echo "<script>alert('Los datos no se pudieron actualizar'); window.location.href='sistema.php'</script>";
    //  echo oci_error();
  }

  
} else {
  // si intenta acceder directamente a esta página, será redirigido a la página de índice
  header('Location: sistema.php'); 
}
```

Comment: **Side note**: Oracle has a to_date function that allows you to convert from a specified format into the Oracle understandable date format

Comment: Yeah, but why is not working with the same format that I use in adding? I am a newbie in Php and oracle,

Comment: Please take a look as this post https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/ullman-bindings.html.  Just allowing variables to become actualised as literal values in your SQL is a sure fire way to get hacked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use prepared statements and bound parameters in PHP oci8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500572/how-to-use-prepared-statements-and-bound-parameters-in-php-oci8)

Comment: No, it doesnt have any relation with my problem

Comment: Undefined function 'TO_DATE' that is the answer of doing that

Comment: The mentioned question actually does have a relation to your question, because we use bind variables to pass some external **data** (of any type) to the SQL statement, not a string concatenation with (default) serialization of everything into string. And Connor already mentioned this along with the link to the docs

Answer (score 1):

Your code is an open door for [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It should be like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE AUTOR SET 
    NOMBRE_AUTOR = :nameautor, FECHA_NACIMIENTO = TO_DATE(:bdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    WHERE ID_AUTOR = :idautor";

$statement = oci_parse($conexion, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':nameautor', $nameautor, 1000, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':bdate', date_format($bdate, 'Y-m-d'), 30, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':idautor', $idautor, 100, SQLT_INT);
$r = oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

You have to use `TO_DATE(...)`, because type like `SQLT_DATE` does not exist. Otherwise you rely on current session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which may change at any time.